# How to limit the number of times a branch is traversed

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

Starting with the toy graph I can find which vertexes are creators by looking for edges that have 'created' out edges:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
graph.traversal().V().as('a').out('created').select('a').values('name')
==>marko
==>josh
==>josh
==>peter
```

I can filter out the duplicates with the dedup step...

```
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().as('a').out('created').select('a').dedup().values('name')
==>marko
==>josh
==>peter
```

...but this only alters the output, not the path followed by the Gremlin. If creators can be supernodes I'd like to tell the query to output 'a' once it finds its first 'created' edge and to then stop traversing the out step for the current 'a' and proceed to the next 'a'. Can this be done?

This syntax has the desired output. Do they behave like I intend?

```
graph.traversal().V().where(out('created').count().is(gt(0))).values('name')
graph.traversal().V().where(out('created').limit(1).count().is(gt(0))).values('name')
```

Is there a better recipe?

EDIT: I just found an example in the where doc (example 2) that shows the presence of a link being evaluated as truth (may not be wording this correctly):

```
graph.traversal().V().where(out('created')).values('name')
```

There's a warning about the star-graph problem, which I think doesn't apply here because, and I'm guessing, there is only one where step that tests a branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last example is the way to go.

```
g.V().where(out('created')).values('name')
```

Strategies will optimize that for you and turn it into:

```
g.V().where(outE('created')).values('name')
```

Also, `.where(outE('created'))` will not iterate through all the out-edges, it's just like a `.hasNext()`, hence no supernode problem.